# Stackoverflow error on factorial using recursion on ktolin

Tags: recursion, kotlin, factorial

This is my code
This gives stack overflow error 30 times on the output console

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){
     var no:Int=Integer.parseInt(readLine())//read input from user and convert to Integer
      var ans:Int=calculateFact(no) //call function and store to ans variable
      println("Factorial of "+no+" is "+ans) //print result
}
fun calculateFact(no:Int):Int //function for recursion
{
if(no==0) {
    return 1 }
return (no*calculateFact(no))   
}
```

I don't know what is error
solve plz

Comment: recursion can never end.

Comment: A little dubugger session would have immediately told you what's wrong. Finding errors in code is what 80% of programming is about. You better grow that skill sooner than later.

Comment: Also some more effort in asking the question would have been nice, for example proper punctuation.

Answer (score 5):

You should return

```
no*calculateFact(no - 1)
```

not

```
no*calculateFact(no)
```

otherwise the recursion can never end.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the mistake in the recursion that was already pointed out, it's worth mentioning that your method will still only work correctly for numbers up to `12`, since `13!` is larger than the maximum value that you can store in an `Int`. Therefore, for numbers `13` and up, you'll essentially get "random" results due to overflow.

If you just use `BigInteger` instead, it will work until the call stack gets too deep and causes a stack overflow, this happens around `8000` on my machine.

```
fun calculateFact(no: BigInteger): BigInteger {
    if (no == BigInteger.ZERO) {
        return BigInteger.ONE
    }
    return (no * calculateFact(no - BigInteger.ONE))
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val no: BigInteger = BigInteger(readLine())
    val ans: BigInteger = calculateFact(no)
    println("Factorial of $no is $ans")
}
```

---

If you want to handle numbers larger than that, you can use a [`tailrec`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#tail-recursive-functions) function (this specific solution is taken from [this](http://blog.richdougherty.com/2009/04/tail-calls-tailrec-and-trampolines.html) article):

```
tailrec fun calculateFact(acc: BigInteger, n: BigInteger): BigInteger {
    if (n == BigInteger.ZERO) {
        return acc
    }
    return calculateFact(n * acc, n - BigInteger.ONE)
}

fun calculateFact(n: BigInteger) : BigInteger {
    return calculateFact(BigInteger.ONE, n)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val n: BigInteger = BigInteger(readLine())
    val ans: BigInteger = calculateFact(n)
    println("Factorial of $n is $ans")
}
```

This will work for numbers up to a couple hundred thousand, your problem with this one will become the time it takes to run instead of the memory constraints.

Answer (score 1):

```
 fun main(args:Array<String>) {
     var no:Int = Integer.parseInt(readLine()) //read input from user and convert to Integer
     var ans:Int=calculateFact(no) //call function and store to ans variable
     println("Factorial of "+no+" is "+ans) //print result
}

fun calculateFact(no:Int):Int { //function for recursion 
    if(no==0) {
        return 1 
    }
    return (no*calculateFact(no - 1)) // you forgot to decrease the no here.
}
```

If you didnot decrease no then it will call the `calculateFact()` method all the time. Please check the code, it will work.